# Getting an error while implementing SSO in our web application using ADFS and SAML2.0 (Sustainsys)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Im Trying to implement SSO in our web application using ADFS and SAML2.0. I am using Windows Server 2012 r2 as my adfs environment. the web application is also in the same environment.

So far when i run the application, I get directed to the main sign in page where i can choose to login using sso. after clicking the sso option, i get redirected to the adfs signon screen and when i try to login with the proper credentials, I get the following error:

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
Saml 

Relying Party: 
https://ADFSDomain/adfs/ls/ 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Policy.PolicyServer.Engine.MissingAssertionConsumerServicesPolicyException: MSIS3077: The AssertionConsumerServices property is not configured for relying party trust 'https://ADFSDomain/adfs/ls/'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.EndpointResolver.LookupAssertionConsumerServiceByUrl(Collection`1 assertionConsumerServices, Uri requestedAssertionConsumerServiceUrl, String scopeIdentity)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.EndpointResolver.FindSamlResponseEndpointForAuthenticationRequest(Boolean artifactEnabled, AuthenticationRequest request, ScopeDescription scopeDescription)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.GetResponseEndpointFromRequest(SamlRequest request, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, ScopeDescription scope)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

This is how the web.config looks like:

```
<sustainsys.saml2 modulePath="/AuthServices" entityId="https://ADFSDomain/adfs/ls/" returnUrl="http://localhost:2181/">
    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="http://ADFSDomain/adfs/services/trust" 
           signOnUrl="https://ADFSDomain/adfs/ls/" 
           allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" 
           binding="HttpRedirect" 
           wantAuthnRequestsSigned="false"
           loadMetadata="true" 
           metadataLocation="https://ADFSDomain/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml">
        <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/newCert.cer" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
  </sustainsys.saml2>
```

Comment: I added an answer but also wanted to double check that you're intending to use a path for the library other than the standard Saml2 path (per the modulePath config item)? If so, I can update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The `entityId` used in your config should be a path specific to your service provider application, not ADFS (the identity provider).

An example config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://yourdomain.com/apppath/Saml2" returnUrl="https://yourapp.com/apppath/" authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Always" outboundSigningAlgorithm="SHA256">
   <identityProviders>
         <add entityId="http://adfs.yourdomain.com/adfs/services/trust" signOnUrl="https://adfs.yourdomain.com/adfs/ls" logoutUrl="https://adfs.yourdomain.com/adfs/ls" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect" loadMetadata="true" metadataLocation="https://adfs.yourdomain.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" />
   </identityProviders>
   <serviceCertificates>
        <add storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" findValue="xxx" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
   </serviceCertificates>
</sustainsys.saml2>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I have tried this and I still get the same error. I suspect that it is an ADFS config problem. (I am using the Saml2 path)

Comment: How is ADFS getting your service provider metadata? If you provided it a static file, you will need to regenerate that metadata file and update it in ADFS as ADFS would have a bad entityId otherwise.